# label залазиет на кнопку

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

После нажатия на кнопку, текст, который должен отобразиться в `label` залазит на кнопку.

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(268, 310)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(268, 310))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(268, 310))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 251, 211))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 260, 251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 251, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог..."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handler)

    def handler(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText('Push')
        self.ui.label.setText('Push')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Решил сам))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохая практика пользоваться абсолютным позиционированием.

Вам надо освоить менеджеры компоновки и тогда ваше приложение может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(268, 310)
#        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(268, 310))
#        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(268, 310))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 251, 211))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 260, 251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 251, 21))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог..."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handler)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1) 
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def handler(self):
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText('Push')
        self.label.setText('Push')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]